# bootstrap get value of the input checkbox via js

Tags: javascript

I have this following markup from bootstrap (my apologies, I am a backend dev, no JS exp):

```
        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="{{i.id}}-choice0">
          <label class="custom-control-label" for="{{i.id}}-choice0">some_answer0</label>
        </div>
        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="{{i.id}}-choice1">
          <label class="custom-control-label" for="{{i.id}}-choice1">some_answer1</label>
        </div>
```

I would like to know how to record the user input(only if the checkbox is `ticked`) for the two `div` elements. Id like an array in JS with the `input` value alongside its `id`. So, perhaps a JS list of list/tuple (please free to suggest an appropriate data structure) looking like so:

```
 some_var=[[id0,some_answer0],[id1,some_answer1]..]
```

Is this possible using just JS?

*UPDATE*

So, after Aaron'e reply, I have this for my JS:

```
    <script>
    var idVals = [];
    function myNewFunction() {
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++){
        if(inputs[i].type == "checkbox"){
            idVals.push([inputs[i].id, inputs[i].checked]);
        }
    }

    console.log(idVals)
    }
    </script>
```

and I am calling the function when the user clicks next page:

```
 <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page={{ i }}" onclick="myNewFunction();" >{{i}}</a></li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will go through every input on the page and check if the input is a checkbox. If so, it adds an array of its `id` and `checked` value (either `true` or `false`) to the idVals array.

```
window.addEventListener("unload", saveAggregateIdValsToLocalStorage);

function getIdValsFromPage(){
    var idVals = [];
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++){
        if(inputs[i].type == "checkbox"){
            idVals.push([inputs[i].id, inputs[i].checked]);
        }
    }
    return idVals;
}

function getIdValsFromLocalStorage(){
    return JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("idVals")) || [];
}

function getAggregateIdVals(){
    return getIdValsFromLocalStorage().concat(getIdValsFromPage());
}

function saveAggregateIdValsToLocalStorage(){
    var aggregateIdVals = getAggregateIdVals();
    window.localStorage.setItem("idVals", JSON.stringify(aggregateIdVals));
}
```

`getIdValsFromPage` returns the idVals from the current page. `getIdValsFromLocalStorage` from all previous pages. `saveAggregateIdValsToLocalStorage` combines both of them and saves to localStorage so you're ready for the next page. This line:

```
window.addEventListener("unload", saveAggregateIdValsToLocalStorage);
```

saves everything before the page changes.

So you should be ready to work with a consistent array across pages like this:

```
console.log(getAggregateIdVals());
```

Comment: firstly, thank you for this. I am however having trouble excecuting this. So, I wrapped your JS in a function, and called it onClick to next page, but I cant see the results :( I have updated the code in the question for your reference. What am I doing wrong? (damn, I need to learn JS at somepoint!) Also, note that the value for the input element is actually in the label element. Perhaps it is this error?

Comment: Looks right, but the console clears when you change pages. Try just calling myNewFunction() directly in the console to avoid the page location change and make sure it works.

Comment: oh wow you were right @Aaron. How can I pass this array from one page to another, do the same computation on the next page and add (the arays) them? Is this possible?

Comment: perhaps I should use localstorage for the above problem^?

Comment: Yes, use localStorage. I can update my answer to show you how if needed.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include a localStorage solution for you.

Comment: I would really apperciate if you could maybe show me a snippet of how to use them - I did try the local storage, but somehow the localstirage does not seem to show this as an array.

Comment: hmm.. for some reason, when I move to the next page and inspect the local storage, I have `idVals` as `[null]` :(

Comment: hang on.. think I found the mistake!

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the return statement to getIdValsFromPage()! Answer updated.

Comment: Please do not apologise! It works perfectly now. I cannot thank you enough for this. REALLY appreciate your help. I will accept the answer now and study the code carefully so that I understand what is going on. Thank you VERY much again.

Comment: Sure thing - I will do. Thank you a TONNE again.

Comment: I've just thought of something. If you ever want to reset these values(for example, when a user loads the first page for the second time), you're going to want to call window.localStorage.removeItem("idVals"); to clear the old set of idVals.

Comment: Funny, I was just about to ask you this question. How do I call this `window.localStorage.removeItem("idVals");` where do I do it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204686/discussion-between-johnj-and-aaron-plocharczyk).